# Property returning original value instead of value updated by method call

Tags: javascript

I'm working through the [EverCraft kata](https://github.com/guyroyse/evercraft-kata) as a way to improve my Javascript skills and have run into a small issue I can't figure out how to make work the way I want.

I'm using [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine) for my tests and have the following test:

```
describe("As an attacker I want to be able to damage my enemies so that they will die and I will live", function () {
    var character = null;

    beforeEach(function () {
        character = new Character();
    });

    it("If attack is successful, other character takes 1 point of damage when hit", function () {

        var beginningHitPoints = character.HitPoints,
            roll = 15;

        character.Attacked(roll);

        expect(character.HitPoints).toBe(beginningHitPoints - 1);
    });
};
```

This test is failing because character.hitPoints is 5, but it is expecting it to be 4.

My code for the Character object is:
(Note: for brevity sake, I've left some code out that is not relevant to this issue)

```
var Character = function () {
    var hitPoints = 5,
        ...
        attacked = function (roll) {
            var isHit = isAHit(roll);

            if (isAHit) {
                hitPoints = hitPoints - 1;
            }
        }
        ...
    ;

    return {
        ...
        HitPoints: hitPoints,
        Attacked: attacked
        ...
    };
};
```

I think I understand what is happening, just not how to make it work the way I expect. I believe that when I am returning `HitPoints: hitPoints`, instead of returning a reference to `var hitPoints = 5` like I expected, it is really returning the value of the variable. In other words, that declaration is the equivalent of `HitPoints: 5`

What I want to know is how, when I call `Attacked` do I get `HitPoints` to return the updated value for `hitPoints`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Character` class is using `hitPoints` property wrongly, you need to have a getter for fetching the updated value of `hitPoints`.

var Character = function () {
    var hitPoints = 5,
        ...
        attacked = function (roll) {
            var isHit = isAHit(roll);

```
        if (isAHit) {
            hitPoints = hitPoints - 1;
        }
    }
    ...
;

return {
    ...
    getHitPoints: function(){
        hitPoints;
    },
    Attacked: attacked
    ...
};
```

};

Then use it like

```
var beginningHitPoints = character.getHitPoints(), roll = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, consider something like this so you don't have to make it a function:

```
 var Character = function () {
    return {
       hitPoints: 5,
       attacked: function (roll) {
        this.hitPoints = this.hitPoints - 1;
       }
    };
 };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QgVMn/3

In this situation, `this` refers to the object we are returning.